# SQL Query - ID Join, Just Duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with Oracle SQL. I have two tables. One has ItemID and DatePurchased and the other has ItemID, CustomerID. I'm trying to join the tables so that I can see only those customers with multiple items.

In other words, if I had:

```
TABLE 1
ItemID---DatePurchased
   1         MAR15
   2         JUN10
   3         APR02
```

and

```
TABLE 2
ItemID---CustomerID
  1          1
  2          1
  3          2
```

I would want this returned:

```
TABLE 3
ItemID--DatePurchased--CustomerID
  1          MAR15         1
  2          JUN10         1
```

(Customer 2 is left out because he only has one item (ItemID=3)).

Any ideas on how to do this in SQL?

Comment: check out SQL aggregates (`COUNT` in this instance), `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ItemID, DatePurchased, CustomerID
from
 (
   select
      T1.ItemID, T1.DatePurchased, T2.CustomerID, 
      count(*) over (partition by T2.CustomerId) as ItemCnt
   from TABLE2 T2
      join TABLE1 T1 on T1.ItemID = T2.ItemID
 ) dt
 where ItemCnt > 1
```

Comment: This one works too. Thanks! Does this save the count and therefore run quicker than the previous suggestion? It seems like it would be quicker, but this is all a learning curve for me.

Comment: I prefer the OLAP functions because there's only one access to the table. Whenever you need details and agregated data from the same table or when you need to access data from other rows you can probably do it with OLAP. And especially when it's not a table but a complex view it's much faster and easier to write.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    T2.ItemID, T2.CustomerID, T1.DatePurchased
from TABLE2 as T2
    inner join TABLE1 as T1 on T1.ItemID = T2.ItemID
where
    T2.CustomerID in
    ( 
        select TT.CustomerID
        from TABLE2 as TT
        group by TT.CustomerID
        having count(*) > 1
    )
```

Comment: This works, but is there a more optimized way of doing this? Does that WHERE IN statement search through the entire list every time? My description was a simplified version of the tables I'm using. In real life each one has about 10MM records, so I want to make sure I'm not going to bog down our system with the query.

Thanks!

Comment: I think dnoeth one will be faster, didn't know if Oracle allows partition by so had to use old style one